# Canvas repeating rectangles aren't unique

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to write a function that allows to make repeated rectangles with different text values, and a flag that changes the color of the box.  I'm having trouble getting the text for each call to the function as well as the correct color to appear on each respective box.  I end up with the last box in a series of calls being the only one with visible text.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

this.buildBox = function(xpos, ypos, width, height, text, colorFlag) {
    ctx.font = '12px Arial';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillStyle = colorFlag === true ? '#ff6666' : '#fff';
    ctx.rect(xpos, ypos, width, height);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    function textFill(text, offset) {
    }

    if(text !== null && text !== undefined) {
      ctx.strokeText(text, xpos + 10, ypos + 20);
    } 
}
// test data
this.buildBox(84,10,64,44, 888, true);
this.buildBox(84,64,64,44, 999, false);
this.buildBox(84,118,64,44, 777, true);
```

To test, try commenting out some of the calls to `buildBox` and see the results in the fiddle below.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5z1Lgtvw/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the draw methods apply only to the things you do in one function call, add the following line as the first in your function:

```
ctx.beginPath();
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

this.buildBox = function(xpos, ypos, width, height, text, colorFlag) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.font = '12px Arial';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillStyle = colorFlag === true ? '#ff6666' : '#fff';
    ctx.rect(xpos, ypos, width, height);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    function textFill(text, offset) {
    }

    if(text !== null && text !== undefined) {
      ctx.strokeText(text, xpos + 10, ypos + 20);
    }
}


// test data
this.buildBox(84,10,64,44, 888, true);
this.buildBox(84,64,64,44, 999, false);
this.buildBox(84,118,64,44, 777, true);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Without this line, the methods `fill` and `stroke` apply to all you have drawn so far. With `beginPath` you consolidate what was done before, and start with a new "section".

Comment: Thank you!  I'm new to canvas and was stuck on this for a while.